# Fetching row from database using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to echo users profile photo using ajax and php but i get nothing but a blank page. Below is my ajax and php code which I have written myself.

**Ajax**

```
$('#profile_photo').html('<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading..." width="20px" height="20px" >');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax( {    
        type: "GET",
        url: "profile_photo.php",             
        dataType: "html",   
        success: function(d) {                    
             $("#profile_photo").html(d); 
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP (profile_photo.php)**

```
<?php  
    // connect to db
    include 'db.php';

    // start session
    session_start();

    // user id 
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $user = $_SESSION['name'];

    // variables

    // profile photo
    $profile_photo_query = mysqli_query($db_var, "SELECT * FROM users_profile_photo WHERE id = '$id'"); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($profile_photo_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $set_profile_photo = $row["image"];
    }

        // for profile photo (encode with base64)
        if ($set_profile_photo == null) {
            echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents("profile_photo/default.png"))."' alt='".$user."' title='".$user."' onContextMenu='return false;'";
        } else {
            echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents("profile_photo/$set_profile_photo"))."' alt='".$user."' title='".$user."' onContextMenu='return false;'";
        }
?>
```

**Html**

```
<div class="prev">
   <span id="profile_photo"></span>
</div>
```

**Css (prev)**

```
.prev {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -80px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.prev img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The ajax loads the loading image (.gif) successfully but shows a blank page when loading image is done loading. I will like to know why the profile photo is not been shown because my php code has no errors.

Comment: Have you tried to see if there are any errors in console log? What if you load direct profile_photo.php, does it show anything?

Comment: Check on your images paths. What exactly do you get in the success ?

Comment: @D.Dimitrov my code now works fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its not the Ajax that loads the .gif.
Its done before with this code:

```
$('#profile_photo').html('<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading..." width="20px" height="20px" >');
```

First of all, you are missing an ">" at he end of your code here:

```
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(file_get_contents("profile_photo/default.png"))."' alt='".$user."' title='".$user."' onContextMenu='return false;'";
```

Check if anything is set to the img src attribute..

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to import `img` tag with php code through ajax response which you want to put it in your html code which isn't possible So try this code. 
In javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax( {    
    type: "GET",
    url: "profile_photo.php",             
    dataType: "html",   
    success: function(d) {                    
         $("#image").attr("src", d);
    }
});
});
```

In php just echo src not full img tag

```
 if ($set_profile_photo == null) {
        // echo just path of file
    } else {
        // echo just path of file
    }
```

In html

```
<div class="prev">
<img id="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think as you are using base64 image, it is not showing. You can just add simple src to the image for showing the image. Here is the example :

```html
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Just change the source according to your actual source.